# assert selenium getAllSelectedOptions() using assertJ

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I haven't been able to do this, so far able to use `getFirstSelectedOption().getText()` to assert selected item from multiple selection element.

Is it possible to assert `getAllSelectedOptions()` `getTex()` using assertJ?
I can loop through `getAllSelectedOptions()` through `foreach` loop

I know i can use `getAllSelectedOptions().get(0).getText())` and increment get(x) for all of selected item.
But is there any elegant solution (without using index)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
//identify a common locator which identifies multiple items and store in a list
List<WebElements> allItems=driver.findElementsById("xa");

System.out.println("The total number of radio  buttons are:" +allItems.size());
for(WebElement eachItem:allItems)
{
System.out.println(eachItem.getText());
}
```